# ZFC results first proved using $V=L$ or the diamond principle?

Tags: set-theory

Are there any examples of ZFC-theorems that were first established with the use of $V=L$ or (otherwise if not) the diamond principle? I am thinking of prediction and confirmation in the same sense that certain results were first established using large cardinals before they were proved in only ZFC (Dehornoy’s work on braids, for example). Or how Martin's axiom was used in the original proof of the Baumgartner-Hajnal theorem (https://mathoverflow.net/a/29957).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a famous example:

It is a theorem of Jensen that $V=L$ implies diamonds on all successor cardinals, thus $V=L$ gives you that $$\forall\kappa\ge\aleph_0\,(2^\kappa=\kappa^+\Longrightarrow\lozenge_{\kappa^+}).$$

> [MR0309729](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=309729) (46 #8834).
> Jensen, R. Björn. *[The fine structure of the constructible hierarchy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484372900010)*.
> With a section by Jack Silver.
> Ann. Math. Logic 4 (1972), 229–308; erratum, ibid. 4 (1972), 443.

(In $\mathsf{ZFC}$, $\lozenge_{\kappa^+}$ implies $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$,  so the significance here is that under $V=L$ we get the reverse implication, that just the cardinal arithmetic gives you strong prediction principles.) Later, it was shown that $\mathsf{CH}$ is consistent with the failure of $\lozenge=\lozenge_{\aleph_1}$, so the displayed result is not a theorem of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

However, Shelah proved that $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ implies $\lozenge_{\kappa^+}$ for all uncountable cardinals $\kappa$, so the consistency result in the previous paragraph is the *only* case where the displayed implication fails. (In fact, Shelah proved a strengthening of this.)

> [MR2596054](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=2596054) (2011m:03084).
> Shelah, Saharon. *[Diamonds](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2010-138-06/S0002-9939-10-10254-8/home.html)*.
> Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 138 (2010), no. 6, 2151–2161.

---

Assaf Rinot has an excellent survey paper clarifying what we know in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ about instances of $\mathsf{GCH}$ and the respective diamond principles and related statements. This should give you additional examples along the same lines.

> [MR2777747](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=2777747) (2012k:03116). Rinot, Assaf. *[Jensen's diamond principle and its relatives](https://blog.assafrinot.com/?p=448)*. In **Set theory and its applications**, 125–156,
> Contemp. Math., 533, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2011.

Actually, many result of Shelah using his pcf techniques are additional examples. And many results by Rinot himself and his collaborators are also of this kind. In particular, in Rinot's page, take a look at his papers on Souslin trees.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your example. There should be two publications, one where the proof uses the additional axiom, and one (later publication) where it is established in ZFC alone. Or otherwise some kind of absoluteness argument in one paper (as in the Baumgartner-Hajnal example). Which theorem do you claim can be proved in ZFC?

Comment: @Jori Ah. I clarified.

Comment: Nice example. Interestingly, most of these prediction and confirmation cases assume GCH/CH (see e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/q/71201/481227), are there also such examples that instead assume $\neg\text{GCH}$/$\neg\text{CH}$ which later turned out to be provable in ZFC? Perhaps a separate question, but if you know...

Comment: Only critique I have for this answer is that Jensen really showed all the diamond statements hold under V=L without the condition Shelah needed (of course), so the would be predication was really much stronger than what can be done in ZFC. An example where this is not the case, would be even more interesting to me.

Comment: More along the lines of the  Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem, which Keisler proved using GCH and Shelah proved in ZFC alone, much later.

Comment: I made this a separate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4852659/1052395 . I have not (yet) accepted your answer because I am still looking for better examples to which the above issues don't apply. But thank you for your high quality answer, it is much appreciated.