# ZFC results first proved using $\neg\text{GCH}$/$\neg\text{CH}$

Tags: set-theory

Are there any examples of ZFC-theorems that were first established assuming $\neg\text{GCH}$/$\neg\text{CH}$ (the negation of the (generalized) continuum hypothesis)? I am thinking of prediction and confirmation in the same sense that certain results were first established using large cardinals before they were proved in only ZFC (Dehornoy’s work on braids, for example). Or how Martin's axiom was used in the original proof of the Baumgartner-Hajnal theorem (https://mathoverflow.net/a/29957). Interestingly, there *are* several such examples that assume GCH or CH (see for instance https://mathoverflow.net/q/71201/481227), such as the Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem, which was first proved by Keisler using GCH and then later by Shelah without this additional assumption.

Comment: I think it would be hard enough just to find interesting theorems that were proved assuming $\neg$CH or $\neg$GCH.

Comment: @user14111 Well, one example I can think of is that MA + ¬CH implies the Suslin hypothesis.

Comment: Lots of theorems proved of $\neg$CH+something. Your question seems to be about theorems proved using just plain ZFC$+\neg$CH.

Comment: That would be ideal yes, but I am also interested in cases with additional assumption. They are after all proofs from ¬CH too. You're welcome to share.